# Python base64 string to PyPng without saving file

Tags: python, base64, pypng

How do you do this without saving to disk and then opening 'out.png' ?

```
    r = requests.get(url)
    mine,encoded =  r.json()[0]['data'].split(',') #if it is segmentation
    decoded = base64.decodestring(encoded)

    if mine == 'data:image/png;base64':
        #TODO do this from memory
        g = open("out.png", "w")
        g.write(decoded)
        g.close()            

        r = png.Reader('out.png')
        print r.read()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `bytes` keyword

```
r = png.Reader(bytes=decoded)
```

Answer (score 0):

`base53.decodestring()` returns a string of the binary data, and according to [this page](https://pythonhosted.org/pypng/png.html) `png.Reader()` can take a string as input, so you just have to link the two together.